# Return part of a string from a function without additional allocation

Tags: string, rust, memory-management, slice, allocation

I would like a function that returns *part* of a larger string that is internally generated without causing a separate allocation for the returned part:

```rust
fn generate_full_string() -> String {"example: 123".to_owned()}
fn generate_partial_string() -> String {
    generate_full_string()[9..].to_owned()
}
```

Here, `generate_partial_string` has the behavior desired: it generates a `String` using some algorithm (modeled here by `generate_full_string`) and then returns part of it, specifically, the portion from the 9th character onwards. The problem here, from my understanding, is that when `to_owned()` is called on the `str` returned from `generate_string()[9..]`, a new heap allocation is created to store the returned partial string data, and the partial string data from `generate_string()[9..]` is copied into it.

Instead, I would like to reuse the allocation created in `generate_full_string`, and use it to store the returned partial string. In other words, I want the `String` value returned from `generate_partial_string` to point to the desired portion of the heap allocation created by `generate_full_string` to hold the full string.

Is it possible to do this in safe Rust? Is there some other API pattern I can use to return a part of a larger string from a function without requiring that function to take ownership of a `String` from its caller's scope?

Comment: If you only want to cut off end of a String you can use [truncate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.truncate). Otherwise I think it's impossible.

Comment: good2know. But, in this case I wish to cut off the *beginning* of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.replace_range()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.replace_range) with an empty string to remove the prefix:

```
fn generate_partial_string() -> String {
    let mut full = generate_full_string();
    full.replace_range(..9, "");
    full
}
```